# why checkbox is not uncheck in jquery or click event not fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why checkbox is not unchecked in jquery or click event, not fire?

I have one checkbox in my demo.The user can uncheck this checkbox, but I am not able to uncheck this checkbox.here is my code

https://jsbin.com/lohaleleba/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
$(function() {
  function signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('--')
  }
  $('#signUpAgree_js').click(signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler)
})
```

```css
#toi-login .form ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

#toi-login .checkbox {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

#toi-login p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #222;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#toi-login .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

#toi-login input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#toi-login .checkbox label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background: #ffffff no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#toi-login .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  background: #3696de;
  border-color: #3696de;
}

#toi-login .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: solid #fff;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 3px;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toi-login">
  <form class="form" action="#" autocomplete="off">
    <ul>
      <li class="checkbox">
        <p> <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="signUpAgree_js"> <label for="agree">I agree with the                <a href="#"> Terms &amp; Conditions </a>and                <a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a> of Times of India</label> </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

could you please tell me how to uncheck or toggle this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just correct the label `for` attribute. The `for` attribute determines which `input` it is associated with and in this case, the ID of `signUpAgree_js` needs to be provided.

```js
$(function() {
  function signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler(e) {
    
    alert('--')
  }
  $('#signUpAgree_js').change(signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler)
})
```

```css
#toi-login .form ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

#toi-login .checkbox {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

#toi-login p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #222;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#toi-login .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

#toi-login input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#toi-login .checkbox label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background: #ffffff no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#toi-login .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  background: #3696de;
  border-color: #3696de;
}

#toi-login .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: solid #fff;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 3px;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toi-login">
  <form class="form" action="#" autocomplete="off">
    <ul>
      <li class="checkbox">
        <p> <input type="checkbox" checked id="signUpAgree_js"> <label for="signUpAgree_js">I agree with the                <a href="#"> Terms &amp; Conditions </a>and                <a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a> of Times of India</label> </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix 2 issues.

1. label `for` attribute must refer to the input id. In this scenario, it should be `signUpAgree_js` instead of `agree`.

   ```
   <label for="signUpAgree_js">
     I agree with the <a href="#"> Terms &amp; Conditions </a>
     and <a href="#"> Privacy Policy</a> of Times of India
   </label>
   ```
2. It has to be a `change` event instead of a `click` event.

   ```
   $(function(){
     function signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           e.stopPropagation();
           alert('--')
     }
     $('#signUpAgree_js').change(signUpAgreeCheckedEventHandler)
   })
   ```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nutboltu/4r37v97v/6/)